# Why are Macro's names being changed all of the sudden?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I am creating VBA macros in my Excel spreadsheet. For the first time today, I noticed that some of my macro names has been changed from 'Email_Comments_TO_AMY' to 'Financial Statement Progress Tracker.xlsm'!Email_Comments_TO_AMY.Email_Comments_TO_AMY'. This has never happened before and the macros have been programmed to certain images for the past two weeks. The new name is not a current macros and therefore, I cannot execute the commands I have assigned to certain checkbox images. This is not a valid macro and, therefore, I cannot run it anymore.

I am assuming that if I delete all of the macros, recreating them, and then reassigning them to each image, I might be able to fix the problem since this happened unexpectedly, it would be incredibly unfortunate if this were to happen again.

Can anyone explain to me what is causing this issue and what steps I can take to prevent it?

Comment: Don't reuse a macro name as a module name.

Comment: I somewhat understand what you are saying. But would you mind explaining the difference between a module and macro please?

Comment: I think I figured it out. Thanks for your help! @BigBen

Answer (score 0):

A module is the page in the VBA Editor screen which holds the macros. When you call a module and a macro the same thing, it changes format to show you the workbook name like in the example you gave above.

Your macros will still work the same if this happens, you can just change it, but it's good practice to not call them the same thing.